# Java Generics: Use generic class as type parameter of another generic class

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way in Java to use a generic class as a type parameter of another generic class?

For example, I have `Message` and `MessageBus` like this:

```
public interface Message<V> {};

public interface MessageBus {
    <V> V execute(Message<V> message);
}
```

It works well now.

And then, I get `Command` and `CommandBus` like this:

```
public interface Command<V> {};

public interface CommandBus {
    <V> V execute(Command<V> command);
}
```

It works well, too.

But, the implementation of `CommandBus` is almost the same as `MessageBus`.
I want to define `MessageBus` as a generic class like this:

```
public interface Message<V> {};
public interface MessageBus<T extends Message> {};
public interface Command<V> extends Message<V> {};
public interface CommandBus extends MessageBus<Command> {};
```

It seems to be fine, but problem comes when I want to define method `execute`:

```
public interface MessageBus<T extends Message> {
    <V> V execute(T<V> message);       // compiles error, T<V> is invalid
    <V> V execute(T message);          // T means Message<Object>, not Message<V>
    <V> V execute(Message<V> message); // CommandBus cannot override Message<V> to Command<V> in subclass
}
```

Note that `V` is different type on each call, so I cannot define `MessageBus` like this:

```
public interface MessageBus<V, T extends Message<V>> {
    /**
     * In this way, each bus can have only one fixed return type.
     * But different return type is expected on different message,
     * just like the first interface above.
     */
    V execute(T message);
}
```

I want to use them like this:

```
public class Command1 implements Command<Integer> {};
public class Command2 implements Command<String> {};
public class Command3 implements Command<String> {};
public class Message1 implements Message<String> {};

CommandBus commandBus;
Integer v1 = commandBus.execute(new Command1());  // fine
String v2 = commandBus.execute(new Command2());   // fine
String v3 = commandBus.execute(new Command3());   // fine
String v4 = commandBus.execute(new Command1());   // should compile error, return type mismatch
String v5 = commandBus.execute(new Message1());   // should compile error, only support Command
```

I will have kinds of `MessageBus`, like `CommandBus extends MessageBus<Command>`, `QueryBus extends MessageBus<Query>`, `EventBus extends MessageBus<Event>` and so on.

How would I implement this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `T` from `Message<T>` gone all of a sudden? That's what's being returned in the previous code.

Comment: @daniu That's the problem: the return type `V` should be a generic type on method `execute`, not on class `MessageBus`. When `Message` goes to type parameter of `MessageBus`, the `V` cannot go there. (I edited the question and renamed `Message<T>` as `Message<V>`, since it is different from `T` in `MessageBus<T extends Message>`)

Answer (score 0):

You lost the `T` from `Message`, which was the original return type.

```
public interface Message<T> {};
public interface MessageBus<T> {};
public interface Command<T> extends Message<T> {};
public interface CommandBus<T> extends MessageBus<T> {};
```

Now your classes will be like

```
class MessageBus<String> {
    String execute(Message<String> m) { ... }
}
class CommandBus<Integer> {
    String execute(Message<Integer> m) { ... }
    Integer execute(Command<Integer> c) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Note that each Message has its own return type, and MessageBus.execute return type T should change with Message<T>, so you cannot use it as type parameter of MessageBus.

Comment: How do you mean "MessageBus.execute return type T should change with Message<T>"?

Comment: daniu? What is your rationale for changing _`MessageBus`_ and _`CommandBus`_ from LiuSXwww's original _`interfaces`_ to concrete _`classes`_?

Comment: „*...How do you mean "MessageBus.execute return type T should change with Message<T>"?...*“ — Am not OP. But my guess, daniu, is he's referring to your _`String execute(Message<Integer> m) { ... }`_. Given a _`Message<Integer>`_ parameterized type for your _`m`_ param of your method, then a method declared as _`CommandBus.execute(Message<Integer>)`_ should return an _`Integer`_. That is to say: The return type of the _`execute()`_ method should be the same type as the type argument that _`Message<T>`_ was instantiated with. In the instance of that part of your answer, that type is _`Integer`_.

Comment: @daniu For a same instance `commandBus` of `CommandBus`, `commandBus.execute(Command<Integer>)` should return an `Integer`, `commandBus.execute(Command<String>)` should return a `String`, and `commandBus.execute(Command<V>)` should return a `V`.

Comment: Hi there @LiuSXwww. Curious to learn: How well has [*my answer above*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252365/4465539) understood your requirements? Click the blue _**Execute**_ button at the bottom of [*the demo*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/8o) to see it work. If anything there isn't clear, just ask.

Comment: @LiuSXwww It is not possible to define two separate methods the way you describe due to type erasure. For Java, the methods `V execute (Message<V> m)` and `T execute(Message<T> m)` have the same erasure and therefore the same signature, and you can't define the same method twice in a class.

Comment: @daniu It is one method with generic type, not two separate methods. As I mentioned in the first part of my description: `public interface MessageBus { <V> V execute(Message<V> message); }`, This `MessageBus` can work very well with `execute(Message<Integer>)` and `execute(Message<String>)` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> „*…How would I implement this behavior?…*“

[*Here's how I'd implement it*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/8o)…

```
public interface MessageBus< S extends Foo< ? > > {

    < T extends Foo< U >, U > U execute( T message );
}
```

I introduced the *`Foo`* interface you see there because in order to be able to do what you say you want to do — *and do it in a **type safe** way* — *`Message`* and *`Command`* needed to be the same ***type***.

In the context of [*this representative example*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/8o), *`Foo`* takes on the responsibility of that necessary commonality. You'd rename *`Foo`* to be something more meaningful in your actual business domain.

> „*...I want to use them like this*:“
>
> ```
>    ...
>    public class Command1 implements Command<Integer> {};
>    public class Command2 implements Command<String> {};
>    public class Command3 implements Command<String> {};
>    public class Message1 implements Message<String> {};
>    ...
> ```

In [*my demo*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/8o) I've confirmed that the solution is usable like this…

```
    CommandBus commandBus = new StandardCmdBus() ;
    
    CharSequence v0 = commandBus.execute(new CharSeqCommand());   
    
    Integer v1 = commandBus.execute(new IntegerCommand());    // fine
    
    String v2 = commandBus.execute(new StringCommand());      // fine    
    
    String v3 = commandBus.execute(new StringMessage());      // fine
    
    /*String v4 = commandBus.execute(new CharSeqCommand());*/ // error: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
```

With the concrete *`Messages`* and *`Commands`* that I also introduced, this gets printed to *`stdout`*…

```
 Hail Bopp!
        666
Heal Setan!
Hell Santa!
```

Comment: It's almost there, but `String v3 = commandBus.execute(new StringMessage());` should compile error. I cannot find any difference between your `CommandBus` and `MessageBus`.

Comment: Do me a favor? Clarify in a teensy-weensy more detail why it „*should compile error*“? Please? I mean what are the conditions under which that specific case „*should compile error*“? It's not crystal clear from your original description. TIA.

Comment: The only difference between your `CommandBus` and `MessageBus` is the `S`, but it's never used. So they are just the same.

Comment: It's mentioned in my description: `String v5 = commandBus.execute(new Message1());   // should compile error`. A command bus should only send commands, no other messages. That is why I want to use generics.

Comment: Thanks. I've played around with two or three different permutations before landing on the one I've presented here. My goal was to arrive at something that was as similar as possible to the original code that you wrote. There's almost certainly a different implementation that will „*compile error*“ under the conditions you want. But I'm reasonably certain that that implementation wouldn't look as similar to your original code as my current implementation does. If I get some spare time again soon, I might take a another stab at it. Thx again. Good problem for a daily coding kata, by the way :)

Comment: „*It's almost there...*“ — You're new here, @LiuSXwww, so you probably don't know this: *You can upvote answers without marking them as accepted*. I've worked on this question as, like I said, a *coding kata*. I don't really do SO for the *internet points*. Learning from interesting coding problems is its own reward. Even so, a little gratitude — *in the form of an upvote* — for me *at least* sharing with you what I've learned, would be appreciated. You know? It might even motivate me to share with you my latest solution demo. Which, in my humble opinion, is the best one of them all. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You already know, from the various compilation errors you got originally, your original implementation can't do what you've now clarified is what you actually want to do. In the comments to his/her answer @daniu aludes to *one* reason why that is.

Your original code wants to do [*something the language forbids*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3-300). Namely: *Override a method using a signature that's totally different from the super signature*.

So you don't want to structure your application the way the code in your original question illustrated. To do what you say it is you *actually* want to do, your original code needs some significant refactors. So does the code in my first answer. Hence this separate answer…

```
public interface MessageBus< V > { 
    
    V evaluate( Message<V> msg );
}

public interface CommandBus< V > { 
    
    V evaluate( Command<V> msg );
}

public interface EventBus< V > { 
    
    V evaluate( Event<V> msg );
}
...
public interface Message < V >{ 
    
    V evaluate( );
}
public interface Command< V > extends Message< V >{ 
    
    V evaluate( );
}
...
public class StandardCmdBus { 
    
    public static <S, T extends Command<S>> S evaluate( T cmd ){ return cmd.evaluate();  }
}
```

[*I demonstrate how that could be actually used*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/8K) like this…

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  
    Stream< Command< ? > > shellCmds = of( () -> 3.14, () -> "javac", () -> "gcc", () -> 42.424242D, () -> "grep", () -> 666);
    
    Stream< Command< ? > > robotCmds = of( () -> "Assemble 666,666,666,666 Cars!", () -> "Exterminate!", () -> "Disallow: /questions/63242515/", () -> 777.9311, () -> "Rescue Will Robinson!", () -> "Kill all humans!", () -> 666);
    
    Stream< Message< ? > > msgs = of( () -> "What hath God wrought?", () -> "Sending out an S.O.S...", () -> "I like apples...", () -> 666, () -> "Friends of space, how are you all? Have you eaten yet? Come visit us if you have time.", () -> "?.?.?", () -> "The answer is...", () -> 42);

    Stream< Event< ? > > evts = of( () -> "The Big Bang", () -> "First Contact", () -> 867.5309, () -> "The Moon Landing", () -> "onLoad()", () -> 666, () -> "The Rapture" );
    
    Stream< Query< ? > > queries = of( () -> "The Ultimate Query...", () -> 42 );
    
    CommandBus< ? > cmdBus = ( cmd ) -> cmd.evaluate( );
    
    MessageBus< ? > msgBus = ( msg ) -> msg.evaluate( );
    
    EventBus< ? > evtBus = ( evt ) -> evt.evaluate( );
    
    QueryBus< ? > qBus = ( q ) -> q.evaluate( );
    
    /* Totally type safe; no unchecked warnings (i.e. no casts invovled) */
    robotCmds.map( StandardCmdBus::evaluate ).forEach( out::println );
    
    /* Less type safe; But totally fine; „uses unchecked or unsafe opertions“ (i.e. casts invovled) */
    use( shellCmds, cmdBus::evaluate ); 
    
    use( msgs, msgBus::evaluate ); 
    
    use( evts, evtBus::evaluate );
    
    use( queries, qBus::evaluate );
    
    Message< String > wtf = ( ) -> "// should compile error";
    
    /* cmdBus.evaluate( wtf );*/ /* error: incompatible types: Message<String> cannot be converted to Command<CAP#1> */ 
    
}
```

…Which prints out…

```
Assemble 666,666,666,666 Cars!
Exterminate!
Disallow: /questions/63242515/
777.9311
Rescue Will Robinson!
Kill all humans!
666
...
-----------

What hath God wrought?
Sending out an S.O.S...
I like apples...
666
Friends of space, how are you all? Have you eaten yet? Come visit us if you have time.
?.?.?
The answer is...
42        
...
-----------

The Ultimate Query...
42

...
```

Your original implementation uses Generics sort of over-zealously.  We all are guilty of that at some point. They are a cool form of polymorphism. But used in the wrong way, they cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: Your interface is similar to the first part of my description. I know it works well. But all the buses are complex and similar. I do not want to repeat myself again and again. Besides, `CommandBus` IS A special `MessageBus`. So I'd like inheritance and generics, just like *Template in C++*, or *Macro in C*. But it seems not allowed in Java.

Comment: If I do not need a return value, I can use `public interface MessageBus<T extends Message> { void execute(T message);}` and `public interface CommandBus<T extends Command> extends MessageBus<T> {}`. This is reasonable and allowed in Java. Now I want the bus to return a value and keep type safe. This is obviously reasonable, but not allowed in Java.

Comment: The key point in my description is: I can define separate type safe buses, repeating myself again and again. I can also make all buses inheriting `MessageBus` or some other base class, and need not repeat myself, but it is not type safe. Now I want to now how to define type safe buses, without repeating myself.

Comment: „*`CommandBus` IS A special `MessageBus`*“ — You said 2 days ago: „*`CommandBus` is **almost** the same as `MessageBus`*“. The „*IS **ALMOST***“ relation is not the „***IS** A*“ relation. You tried _`MB{<V> V execute(Message<V> message);} <- CB{<V> V execute(Command<V> command);}`_. But [*that's illegal*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3). The methods have [*different signatures*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4). To override, method params must be ***exactly the same***. Not subtypes. But ***exactly the same***.

Comment: „*just like Template in C++*“  — The similarity between Java's Generics and C++'s Templates is only superficial. They are fundamentally different.  — „*But it seems not allowed in Java*“ — What you probably want is „[_Double Dispatch_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)“. So you're right. Java don't do that OOTB. Have you considered [*overloading*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) as an option? @daniu hinted at that in your Q's comments. The [*Visitor Design Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might also be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

„*…`CommandBus` IS A special `MessageBus`…*“

Consider the following class structure. Think of *`MessageBus`* as *`Animal`*, *`CommandBus`* as *`Cat`* , *`Message`* analogous to *`Food`* and *`Candy`* analogous to *`Command`*…

```
 +----------------+
 |     Animal     |
 +----------------+                +----------------+
 |eat(Food)       |                |      Food      |
 |                                 |                |
 |                |                +--------^-------+
 +-------^--------+                         |
         |                                  |
         |                      >-----------------------<
 +----------------+             |                       |
 |      Cat       |    +----------------+      +----------------+
 +----------------+    |      Candy     |      |      Grass     |
 |eat(Food)       |    |                |      |                |
 |eat(Candy)      |    +----------------+      +----------------+
 |eat(Grass)      |
 +----------------+
```

Anything that „***IS** A `Animal`*“ absolutely ***MUST*** „*`eat(Food)`*“. If it doesn't eat food, then it is ***NOT*** an *`Animal`*. That is what inheritance is all about.

Analogously: Anything that „***IS** A `MessageBus`*“ absolutely ***MUST*** „*`execute(Message)`*“. If it doesn't execute a message, then it is ***NOT*** a *`MessageBus`*.

To say: „*A command bus should only send commands, no other messages*“ is exactly like saying:  „*A `Cat` should only eat `Candy`, no other `Food`*“. If it doesn't eat *`Food`*, then it is ***NOT*** an *`Animal`*.

Sure, a *`Cat`* ***can*** eat *`Candy`* and *`Grass`* under *specialized* circumstances. It's not a *`Cat's`* default behavior though.

> „…*I'd like inheritance and generics…*“

It is possible to have both. But I think *the expectations* you have for combining them, are *not* possible.

If you truly want inheritance, then you must accept that a *`Cat`* MUST *`eat(Food)`*. If you want a *`CommandBus`* that does not *`execute(Message)`*, then you ***do not*** want inheritance.

Sure, it's possible to implement a *`CommandBus`* to *`execute(Command)`*. But that must be in ***addition*** to *`execute(Message)`* Because of ***inheritance***, *`execute(Message)`* is the default behavior for *`CommandBus`*.

Comment: `Animal<T extends Food>` means an `Animal` **MUST** `eat` some kind of `Food`, not all kinds of `Food`. `Cat extends Animal<Candy>` means a `Cat` **MUST** `eat(Candy)`, but **NOT** other `Food`. This is allowed in Java, and same as the real world: Animals eat food, but there are many animals only eat meat, and many animals never eat meat.

Comment: The key point is: `MessageBus<T extends Message>` means a `MessageBus` **MUST** `execute(T)`, this `T` is a special kind of `Message`, not all kinds of `Message`. So `CommandBus extends MessageBus<Command>` means a `CommandBus` **MUST** `execute(Command)`, **NOT** `execute(Message)`.

Comment: You can try it: `public class Message {}; public class Command extends Message {}; public class MessageBus<T extends Message> { public void execute(T message) {} }; public class CommandBus extends MessageBus<Command> {};`. This `CommandBus` can **ONLY** execute `Command`, **NOT** other `Message`. Obviously, this `CommandBus` is still a special `MessageBus`.

Comment: Awesome @LiuSXwww! You've solved your problem! Congratulations! I'd be very grateful if you shared a link to a working demo. I learn the most when I learn from my mistakes. Also, you should post an explanation of your solution. Please? You are allowed to post answers to your own questions, for the good of the community looking for similar solutions. I will totally upvote it! TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I've not solved my problem. This solution cannot work with `Message<V>`.  I posted this question to find a solution to make `CommandBus extends MessageBus<Command>` and `<V> V execute(Command<V>)` type safe. I can easily achieve any one of these two goals, but not both of them at the same time.

Comment: „*...I can easily achieve any one of these two goals, but not both of them at the same time...*“ — And has any of the code, diagrams, demos or comments that I've shared with you helped you to realize that it's not possible to achieve both of them at the same time?